# Mongodb $lookup to merge collections into a new one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

First of all, I'm new to mongodb so my question can be quite stupid.

I've two collections which I merged using **`$lookup`**

```
db.information.aggregate([     
    {       
        $lookup: {           
            from: "extra_info",
            localField: "identification", 
            foreignField: "identification",  
            as: "extra_info"         
        }    
    } 
])
```

As an output I get the "collection" that I want but it is not stored in 
the `db.information` collection.

Any hint to make that happen?

Comment: I really don't know what to do, any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) in aggregation pipeline to save the aggregated data to a new collection:

```
db.information.aggregate([     
{       
    $lookup: {           
        from: "extra_info",
        localField: "identification", 
        foreignField: "identification",  
        as: "extra_info"         
    }    
},
{ 
    $out : "newcollection"   // name of the collection to save the lookup in 
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did that but the output I get is the following one: WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }). A new strange entry is added but the documents are not modified